# Configuring babel plugin with webpack

Tags: webpack

I have my simple webpack.config file that does what i want below.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.normalize(__dirname + '/src/js/main')],
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel',
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'js')],
                query: {
                    plugins: ['transform-runtime'],
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'style!css',
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'css')]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

It compile my es2015 just as i wanted. However, i intend to use babel plugin [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-incremental-dom)

I installed the plugin as explained in the doc. I then added a `.babelrc` file in the root folder where my webpack.config is with the settings

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["incremental-dom"]
}
```

. My plugin is not compiling my jsx texts as i was expecting. I m thinking may be i m not configuring my plugin correct in my webpack. Please what am i missing ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe it is because you test for `test: /\.js$/,` try ti use `test: /\.jsx?$/,` Fix the included files too.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i don't have .jsx files initially . But seing your comment makes me added one to test. It still didn't work. As for the includes. My js files are in src/js . I think that should be fine shouldn't it?